# How to access history prop from a parent component using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a method showInfo that is accessed by two components Child1 and Child2.

initially i had the showInfo method within Child1 component like below

```
const Child1 = ({history}: RouteComponentProps) => {
    type Item = {
        id: string,
        name: string,
        value: string,
    };

    const showInfo = (item: item) => {
        const id = item.id;
        const value = item.value;
        const handleRouteChange = () => {
            const path = value === 'value1' ? `/value1/?item=${itemId}` : `/value2/?item=${itemId}`; 
            history.push(path);
        }

       return (
           <Button onClick={handleRouteChange}> Info </Button>
       );
   }


   return (
       <SomeComponent 
           onDone = {({ item }) => {
               notify({
                   actions: showInfo(item)
               }) 
           }}
       />
   );
```

}

the above code works. but now i have another component child2 that needs to use the same method showInfo.

the component child2 is like below

```
const Child2 = () => {
   return (
       <Component 
           onDone = {({ item }) => {
               notify({
                   actions: showInfo(item)
               }) 
           }}
       />
   );
```

}

Instead of writing the same method showInfo in Child2 component i thought of having it in different file from where child1 and child2 components can share the method showInfo.

below is the file with name utils.tsx that has showInfo method

```
 export const showInfo = (item: item) => {
        const id = item.id;
        const value = item.value;
        const handleRouteChange = () => {
            const path = value === 'value1' ? `/value1/?item=${itemId}` : 
            `/value2/?item=${itemId}`; 
            history.push(path); //error here push is not identified as no 
            //history passed
        }

       return (
           <Button onClick={handleRouteChange}> Info </Button>
       );
   }


   return (
       <SomeComponent 
           onDone = {({ item }) => {
               notify({
                   actions: showInfo(item)
               }) 
           }}
       />
   );
```

}

With the above, i get the error where i use history.push in showInfo method. push not defined.

this is because history is not defined in this file utils.tsx

now the question is how can i pass history from child1 or child2 components. or what is the other way that i can access history in this case.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

**EDIT:**

notify in child1 and child2 is coming from useNotifications which is like below

```
const useNotifications = () => {
    const [activeNotifications, setActiveNotifications] = React.useContext(
        NotificationsContext
    ); 
    const notify = React.useCallback(
         (notifications) => {
             const flatNotifications = flatten([notifications]);
             setActiveNotifications(activeNotifications => [
                 ...activeNotifications,
                 ...flatNotifications.map(notification => ({
                     id: notification.id,
                     ...notification,
                 });
             },
             [setActiveNotifications]
    )
    return notify;
}
```

Comment: iirc you can import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom" and then do const history = useHistory()

Answer (score 0):

While you could potentially create a custom hook, your function returns JSX.  There's a discussion about returning JSX within custom hooks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62337860/12010984).  IMO, this is not so much a util or custom hook scenario, as it is a reusable component.  Which is fine!

```js
export const ShowInfo = (item: item) => { // capitalize

   const history = useHistory(); // use useHistory

   // ... the rest of your code

}
```

Now in Child1 and Child2:

```js
return (
  <SomeComponent 
    onDone = {({ item }) => {
      notify({
        actions: <ShowHistory item={item} />
      }) 
    }}
  />
);
```

You may have to adjust some code in terms of your `onDone` property and `notify`  function, but this pattern gives you the reusable behavior you're looking for.

Comment: i am getting invalid hook call error. hooks can only be called inside of the body of the function component. how should i call the showInfo method inside child1 and child2 components now. thanks.

Comment: Which component is that error coming from?

Comment: both the child1 and child2 components.

Comment: notify is coming from const {notify} = useNotifications();

Comment: Can we see more of the logic in that hook?