# Why not return state and child together in react?

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

This code seems to work. Nobody does this. What exactly is wrong with it? Under what conditions will it produce bugs?

```
function App(){
    const [b1, n1] = button()
    const [b2, n2] = button()
    const [input1, text] = input()
    return <div>
      <div>Total: {n1}+{n2}={n1+n2}. That's {text}.</div>
      <div>{b1} {b2} {input1}</div>
      </div>;
}

function button() {
  const [n, setN] = React.useState(0)
  const b = <button onClick={()=>setN(n=>n+1)}>Increment</button>
  return [b, n]
}

function input() {
  const [t, setT] = React.useState("okay")
  const i = <input type="text" value={t} onChange={e=>setT(e.target.value)}/>
  return [i, t]
}
```

https://jscomplete.com/playground/s752284

It's tidy, so I would like to use it if it's fine.

**Edit to clarify:** Suppose you need to elevate state from child component to parent. There are many ways. Pass down a `ref`, pass down `setState`, pass down `dispatch`, etc. This method doesn't require any passing down, just passing up. Custom hooks typically don't return JSX for some reason. Is there some hidden problem with this pattern?

**Edit 2**: Extended example

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62186513/confusion-about-this-react-custom-hook-usage.  Difference is what kind of JSX you return.

Comment: to clarify the point above: basically be aware of the difference between returning a react element (jsx), which is fine, and returning a react component, which isn't. In the example provided by the OP, they are returning an element, and that's acceptable.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that you basically never want to define a component (i.e. a function returning JSX) in the body of any component or effect.

Answer (score 1):

None. It's totally fine. It has even a name, *custom hooks*: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

One of the convention is to give it a name that starts with `use`. That also mean that you need to follow all the rules associated with hooks. Documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: I've never seen a custom hook return a JSX element though. I can't think of any problems with it so I imagined there was some reason, because it is of great use with things like text fields and checkboxes.

Comment: Why not? A JSX is just an object. In fact, I bet you already use a library that does that.  https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/dev/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L321
It's fine, really.

Comment: They're still technically still returning just the element! I'll go ahead and use this pattern though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `state` directly, why you trying to get it from a function call ? Why can't you create it directly inside your component which is really more readable. And keep this complete part `<button onClick={()=>setN(n=>n+1)}>Increment</button>` inside the component instead of the way it's given. It's better to write your code in a more readable manner. Otherwise, it becomes too complicated when it comes to much bigger components.

Comment: Suppose a form has ten inputs and buttons in it. Keeping the entire form in the parent and passing down setters seems messier to me than having children return their own state. See my edits above.